# rest api to call list item based on another column

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

I have `ListA` and `ListB`.
`ListA` has fields with values ( Doc code[A1], Project number[008]) and ListB has fields (Project path[//bank.com], Project number[008]).
 We have one dropdown and button in webpart. Dropdown is populated with doc code. 
As of now when we select doc code in DD and click on button it is fetching respective prj no. from `ListA`. now we want to fetch the prj path from `ListB` when doc code is selected in DD.
 Like when A1 is selected in dropdown I should get value "//bank.com" as project number is foreign key and corresponding to value.

How to achive this via rest api, we have o365.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Expecting that **ListA**  '*PROJECTNUMBER*' field is a lookup field in **ListB**.

First get '*DOCCODE*' & '*ID*' fields of the each item from **ListA**. Then on binding Dropdown use '*ID*' field as value attribute.

It may look like this,

```
<select>
  <option value="1">A1</option>
  <option value="2">A2</option>
</select>
```

Now on the button click, you will get selected option value (`selectedId`).
Then call `GetProjectPath` function,

```
function GetProjectPath(selectedId)
{
        getItems("/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListB')/Items?$filter= PROJECTNUMBER/ID eq "+selectedId+"&$select=PROJECTPATH").done(function(data){
                console.log("NO.OF ITEMS: "+data.d.results.length);
                data.d.results.forEach(function(item){
                        var projectPath = item.PROJECTPATH;

                });
        });
}

function getItems(url){

    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}
```